# Excel export XML validation with default value

Tags: xml, excel, validation, xsd

Since I need to ensure an XML element does not leave blank, I have imported an XSD schema to excel with default="dummy email" attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string" default="testing@gmail.com"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I have also enabled "validate data against schema for import and export" option under XML Map properties. When I want to test does the XSD schema imported in excel does working, I intentionally leave blank on the element and no "testing@gmail.com" auto-filled nor error pops up upon XML export. It is allowed to leave blank on the XML output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<note>
    <to>haha@hotmail.com</to>
    <from/>
    <heading>Hello</heading>
    <body>You are beauty</body>
</note>
```

I have tried different kinds of validations and I cannot make the default value working upon output from Excel to XML. Does anyone has insight on this?